# Getting access to each element of class objects vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have 2 classes in my code, which in first one I use the second class for my vector type:

```
class Chillncode
{
private:
    std::vector <Square> squares;
}
```

and this is *Square class header:*

```
class Square
{
private:
    std::vector < std::vector <int> > position = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
public:
    std::vector < std::vector <int> > getPosition();
}
inline std::vector < std::vector <int> > Square::getPosition()
{
    return position;
}
```

Now, I want to use each elements of *squares vector* like an object, I mean I want to have access to *position vector* in *Square class* with *Square::getPosition* function.

Below wrong code is what I write for this problem:

```
Square sqObject;
squares.push_back(sqObject);
std::vector < std::vector<int> > tempVector = {{i, j}, {i + (sides - 1), j + (sides - 1)}};
squares[squares.end()].getPosition() = tempVector;
```

Regards :)

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: `squares.end()` returns an iterator, referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container. And vector's `operator []` excepts an index, so you cannot have `squares[squares.end()]`. If you want to get the last element you can use vector's `back()` method instead.

Comment: This "I want to have access to position vector in Square class" confuses me, becaue the vector is not inside Square class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous but I have the impression that you need a `Setter` much more than a `Getter`:

```
void setPosition(std::vector < std::vector <int> > tempVector) 
{
    position = tempVector;
};
```

That what I understand when reading this assignment:

```
getPosition() = tempVector
```